# line justification in ggplot using geom_path or geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking for advice/information regarding line justification when using ggplot geom_line, geom_path or geom_segment.

In my scenario, I have directed data. I.e a to b and b to a. For each, I would like to offset the line size so that it is clear what volume applies in each direction.

I have provided a reprex below where the lines are plotted directly on top of one another.

I assume one option is to tweak origins and destinations of the paths to account for the overlap but am hoping that their is an inbuilt function which can do this.

Thanks in advance.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.0.4
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.4

# create sample data
network_data <-
  tibble(origin_x = c(1,2), origin_y= c(1,2), dest_x = c(2,1), dest_y = c(2,1), flow = c(2, 3))

#generate plot
ggplot(network_data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = origin_x, y = origin_y, xend = dest_x, yend = dest_y, size = flow, colour = origin_x), alpha =0.5)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could try `geom_curve` with a `curvature` argument to bend the lines outward:

```
ggplot(
  data = network_data,
  mapping = aes(
    x = origin_x,
    y = origin_y,
    xend = dest_x,
    yend = dest_y,
    size = flow,
    color = origin_x
  )
) +
geom_curve(
  alpha = 0.5,
  arrow = arrow(
    type = "closed",
    angle = 10
   ),
  arrow.fill = "black",
  curvature = 0.1,
  lineend = "round"
)
```

Comment: Thanks @user102162. Neat trick. In a perfect world they will be parallel to the center line.